# Unity3D checking if a point is inside a game object

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to check in Unity if a point(x location of touch,y location of touch) is inside a game object created(Rectangle shaped), if yes, start and spin it around.

I am pretty new to Unity but I tried doing it myself, here is what

```
    Rigidbody rb;
    float x, y;
    MeshCollider col;
    Vector3 v;
    bool bo = true;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        col = rb.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
    }
void Update()
{
    if (bo != true)
        rb.transform.Rotate(Vector3.back, Time.deltaTime * 200, Space.World);
    if (Input.touchCount == 1)
    {
        x = Input.GetTouch(0).position.x;
        y = Input.GetTouch(0).position.y;
        Debug.Log(x + "DOTS " + y);
        v = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
        if (col.bounds.Contains(v))
            bo = false;
    }

}
```

My console is not showing anything, also if I type `Debug.Log("HELLO");` and I can't pretty much check myself so that is pretty much my code, appreciate any help.

Comment: To clarify, you **aren't** seeing your `Debug.Log` statement?

Comment: @jerdak nope, the way I am checking if the collider contains a point is correct?

Comment: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/scripting/on-mouse-down

Comment: @JoeBlow I am using android and not PC, onmousedown is not a function.

Comment: Hi David - FYI it **works fine** on Android/iOS.  For simple handling, it's great

Comment: @JoeBlow Nice then, Thanks!

Comment: But do make sure first if your object has collider attached in order to make `OnMouseDown` work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't get Log due to you are testing on PC, not on mobile device.

In order to check if the touch point is in bounds of gameObject fire a ray from camera:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
#else
        if(Input.touches.Length == 1 && Input.touches[0].phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            Ray ray =  Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.touches[0].position);
#endif

            int layerMask = (1 << YOUR_TARGET_LAYER_ID);
            RaycastHit[] hits = Physics.RaycastAll(ray, 100f, layerMask);

            foreach(RaycastHit hit in hits)
            {
                if(hit.collider == col)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Bingo!!");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Note that I used precompiler directives to make possible this code work on mobile device and on PC.

**YOUR_TARGET_LAYER_ID** is a layer id of the target you want to only be resposive to ray cast. This will ensure that if some other object is covering the target, it will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you.. Kind of complex to me as I am a total beginner.

Comment: @Jerry Switalski Don't you think that mouse position also works with devices for single touch?

Comment: You can see [this tutorial](http://www.hamzahasan.com/simple-swipe-gesture-unity/) for swipe I wrote. Completely without `touches` and 100% tested :)